# Можно ли в QPalette передать rgb?

Tags: python, pyqt5, цвета, qt-designer

Допустим у меня есть конструкция, которая меняет цвет основной формы :

```
self.color = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor(QtCore.Qt.green, self)
self.setPalette(QtGui.QPalette(self.color))
```

Могу ли я как-нибудь вместо используемого В Qt цвета, передать rgb ?

Comment: P.S. Установить передать rgb я хочу именно во второй строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов, - при помощи конструктора `QColor(r, g, b, alpha)` [реф](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QColor-2)

Как результат:

```
self.setPalette(QtGui.QPalette(QColor(255,0,0,255)))
```

Comment: Почему я не могу передать tuple, полученный из self.color.getRgb()?

Comment: @FOX_i_K потому что getRgb не возвращает тупл, а инициализирует аргументы значениями из объекта color. Прсмотрите в доке